# Get key parameters from imported Elliptic Curve key in ASN.1 format

Tags: cryptography, asn.1, elliptic-curve

I need to write code that gets as input Elliptic Curve key in ASN.1 format.

The input byte array is next:

> 308187020100301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D030107046D306B0201010420E699203AC5BCFE36402EBD0AC9E8E21CC6FAD5828A61297EA747468FFF4DBB20A144034200047E05188A03EA81E853B9F6AC5F20DCA1A1CA828FD7CD5D92161FB2120C35EAC52EAB079ED01A510123057C322DDFF95E239D6063055BC90858D161D71DE707F8

Online parser shows me the next structure:

[image: Result of online ASN.1 parser]

To use key as I want I need to get `public value X`, `public value Y` and `private value` from this structure, at least I think so. But I do not know how.

I have searched information about `OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.2.1` and `OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7`. I've found [this document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5753#section-7%22RFC5753%22). But there is no description of fields of ASN.1 structure.

How can I get required parameters from imported data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's commonly known as a PKCS#8 structure, which is the "Private-Key Information Syntax Specification". It only contains the *unencrypted* part of a PKCS#8 private key.

So this is in [PKCS#8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#appendix-A):

```
PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version Version,
    privateKeyAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier {{PrivateKeyAlgorithms}},
    privateKey PrivateKey,
    attributes [0] Attributes OPTIONAL
}
```

The AlgorithmIdentifier is [taken from PKCS#5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#appendix-C)

```
AlgorithmIdentifier { ALGORITHM-IDENTIFIER:InfoObjectSet } ::= SEQUENCE {
    algorithm ALGORITHM-IDENTIFIER.&id({InfoObjectSet}),
    parameters ALGORITHM-IDENTIFIER.&Type({InfoObjectSet}
    {@algorithm}) OPTIONAL
}
```

The [Elliptic Curve Private Key structure](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915#):

```
ECPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    version        INTEGER { ecPrivkeyVer1(1) } (ecPrivkeyVer1),
    privateKey     OCTET STRING,
    parameters [0] ECParameters {{ NamedCurve }} OPTIONAL,
    publicKey  [1] BIT STRING OPTIONAL
}
```

Oh, and encoded in DER, the [Distinguished Encoding Rules (study version)](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf) - you may not be able to rule out BER completely, which is a more loosely defined and therefore harder to parse structure). PKCS#8 defines BER unfortunately.

Oh, yeah, the public key is in uncompressed point format. Don't forget to strip away the `00` from the bit string.

Happy parsing.